# How can I validate an object or array with react and yup?

Tags: reactjs, yup

I have to validate a react form using YUP. In it I have a State:{name: ""} And other objects or attributes that depend on their obligation, depending on the value of the initial "State". I found the .when function that I use in the following example

In my validation, if a value other than "GG" "FF" is obtained, the field must be required

```
export const formValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  state: Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().required("*Required"),
  }),

  age: Yup.number()
    .when("state.name", {
      is: (value) => value !== "FF" && value !== "GG",
      then: Yup.number().required("Required"),
      otherwise: Yup.number(),
    })
});
```

It works perfectly on the age attribute. But when you apply the same logic to an object or an array, it stops working.

```
export const formValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  state: Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().required("*Required"),
  }),

  age: Yup.number()
    .when("state.name", {
      is: (value) => value !== "FF" && value !== "GG",
      then: Yup.number().required("Required"),
      otherwise: Yup.number(),
    })

  department: Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().when("state.name", {
      is: (value) => value !== "FF" && value !== "GG",
      then: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      otherwise: Yup.string(),
  }),
});
```

For example, here I apply the same logic on the object Department: {name: ""} and it doesn't work anymore. The value "state.name" is always undefined, does not seem to have access from within the object

From already thank you very much
I tried to validate it in several ways, changing the comparison operators. But it always gives me the same error

Comment: You are missing a comma after the "age" object.